# Why did my Chickpea water congeal?

Tags: chickpeas

I cooked a bag of chickpeas in a slow cooker, just water and the peas.
Once the peas were soft I ate them with the water they were cooked in, like a bean soup.
Once that cooled the "soup" congealed like jello.

I didn't know it would do that. Is that good for you...I mean it looked like something that would clog your arteries.

Comment: In recent times, people have been using the water from canned chickpeas as an egg white replacement in baking, referred to as aquafaba. I wonder if that could have something to do with the consistency of the liquid.

Answer (score 4):

Chickpeas are starchy, so it's natural that the liquid they are cooked in will thicken when it cools. It will not 'clog your arteries' - food doesn't travel directly to your bloodstream in the form in which you eat it.